# Prevent column-count breaking inner elements

Tags: angularjs, css, ionic-framework

I am trying to create a responsive image wrap gallery. Each image will have a header. I distribute them using  column-count of webkit.

The problem is this: I've specified a container to be "relative". Inside that container, I have an "absolute" header followed by an image. What seems to be happening in some values of column-count is that the header is going to another column and the image in the next. I need them both to be together at all times and I'm surprised why the absolute within relative container is not doing that.

A codepen for reference: http://codepen.io/pliablepixels/full/YwWLzy/

The core image gallery code is:(SO insists I include a code fragment when posting a codepen link, so here goes)

```
   <div style="-webkit-column-count:{{ cols }};-webkit-column-gap:0px;line-height:0px;">
       <span ng-repeat="image in images">
           <div style="position:relative">
               <div class="my_header">Header</div>
               <img class="scaled_image" src={{ image.src }} />
           </div>
       </span>
   </div>
```

Please change the column values and note the header behavior.

How does one solve this? (Note I must use an img tag - can't use background-image)

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Columns**

To protect elements from breaking and keep them entirely in a column you can add these properties:

```
.element {
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
              page-break-inside: avoid; /* Firefox */
                   break-inside: avoid; /* IE 10+ */
}
```

Your fixed example http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rxMWxa

**Header**

Such behaviour occurs because you've added `line-height:0px` to your container div. So you can just return header's `line-height` value to `normal`. Fixed that in codepen.

Comment: Thank you Anton - this does fix the text positioning, but it does not fix my main problem of the header and image attaching to different columns. If you look at your codepen for col=5, you will notice the header for the 3rd column is actually stuck to the bottom of the 2nd col.

Comment: Ok, now I understood what the question is. I've updated my answer that solves your main problem. Is it correct now?

Comment: Anton, thank you - the break-avoid is exactly what I needed to keep the header from moving to another column. I've accepted it as it was an answer to my original q. However, this introduces a side effect where sometimes, images are being cut off into two columns. I can't reproduce it in the codepen, but here is a look at what's happening in my real app - http://imgur.com/dznJspB -- note the picture of garage - split into two columns. Any idea on why this may be happening?

Answer (score 1):

Using line-height sometimes can make headache. Try to use padding like below:

```
.my_header {
background-color: red;
padding: 2px 4px;
line-height: normal;
}
```